# How do you enable drag and drop within a VSPackage ToolWindow?

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, vs-extensibility, vspackage

I have a WPF user control that provides drag and drop functionality within that control.  When the user control is hosted within a WPF app, all works fine.  However when it is hosted within a `VSPackage` `ToolWindow`, drop is disabled altogether.

In this particular case I'm trying to drag a selected item in a draggable list box (left side of diagram below) onto a canvas on the right side.

[image]

The drag can be initiated with `DoDragDrop`, such as:

```
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        if (e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            dragStartPoint = null;

        if (dragStartPoint.HasValue)
        {
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, Content, DragDropEffects.Copy);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

But then drop is not allowed anywhere in the tool window.

What kind of conditions would prevent drag and drop within a tool window, and what settings changes are necessary to enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was found in [Alin Constantin's Blog](http://alinconstantin.blogspot.com/2010/02/drag-and-drop-in-visual-studio-2010.html), and pointed out by user [Notre](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/80e0e9b9-8d62-4c70-aca6-8e4970515ba0) on MSDN.  I needed to handle ALL the drag and drop related events so that the VS shell doesn't intercept them.  In my case, I needed to handle the `DragOver` event in the `Canvas` control:

```
    protected override void OnDragOver(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDragOver(e);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```